# How to Disable a parent page when a RadWindow opens without set_modal(true)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, telerik, radwindow

How to Disable a parent page when a RadWindow opens with out setting the value of set_modal property true?

```
var oWnd = radopen(finalURL, null, width, height);
oWnd.setUrl(finalURL);
oWnd.set_modal(true);     //// Without this line ?
oWnd.set_visibleStatusbar(false);
oWnd.show();
return oWnd;
```

Comment: What are the issues you are facing if it is getting opened?

Comment: Its showing error in IE so want to skip the built in blur method..

Answer (score 1):

Old versions can throw errors under IE when in an iframe because of an IE bug. THis is fixed in later releases, so you should upgrade. More details are available here: http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/aspnet-ajax/window/details/opening-a-modal-radwindow-on-page-load-inside-radwindow-under-ie9-and-ie10.

The fix for that is essentially to focus something before the dialog shows up, e.g.:

```
function fix()
{
    document.documentElement.focus();
    Sys.Application.remove_load(fix);
}
Sys.Application.add_load(fix);
```

Otherwise, you can mimic the modal background div with a div of your own. Here is an example (even though it targets the RadNotification control: http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/aspnet-ajax/notification/details/how-to-make-a-modal-radnotification.

Here is the essence:

```
    function showModalDiv(sender, args)
    {
        if (!modalDiv)
        {
            modalDiv = document.createElement("div");
            modalDiv.style.width = "100%";
            modalDiv.style.height = "100%";
            modalDiv.style.backgroundColor = "#aaaaaa";
            modalDiv.style.position = "absolute";
            modalDiv.style.left = "0px";
            modalDiv.style.top = "0px";
            modalDiv.style.filter = "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(style=0,opacity=50)";
            modalDiv.style.opacity = ".5";
            modalDiv.style.MozOpacity = ".5";
            modalDiv.setAttribute("unselectable", "on");
            modalDiv.style.zIndex = (sender.get_zIndex() - 1).toString();
            document.body.appendChild(modalDiv);
        }
        modalDiv.style.display = "";
    }

    function hideModalDiv()
    {
        modalDiv.style.display = "none";
    }
```

And some event handlers:

and some CSS to ensure snug fit in the viewport:

```
        html, body, form
        {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            height: 100%;
        }
```